# Entries Field Type showing all entries instead of entries selected

Tags: entries, matrix

I am new to craft and twig and need some help showing only added entries to matrix block. What I have now is showing all entries from the section. I may be going about this all wrong, I don't know. I have 11 entries but only want to show the 6 I have added to the block.

[image]

[image]

```
    {% for block in entry.sessionsContent.all() %}

{% switch block.type %}

    {% case "sessionsHeader" %}
    <section class="small-header" style="background-image: url({{ siteUrl }}/images/background-images{{ block.backgroundImage.one().getUrl() }});">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="small-header-title">
            <h1>{{ block.headerTitle }}</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    {% case "sessionsIntro" %}
    <div class="sessions-intro">
            <div class="intro-title">
                <h2>{{ block.introTitle }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="intro-description">
                <p>{{ block.introDescription }}</p>
            </div>
    </div>

    {% case "sideBlock" %}
    {% if block.isWhiteBackground %}
        {% set divColor = 'white-background' %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if block.isBlockOnTheRight %}
        {% set divPosition = 'float-right' %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="side-block" style="background-image: url({{ siteUrl }}/images/background-images{{ block.blockBackgroundImage.one().getUrl() }})">
        <div class="standard_wrapper {{divPosition}} {{divColor}}">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="block-title"><h2>{{ block.blockTitle }}</h2></div>
                <div class="block-teaser"><p>{{ block.blockTeaser }}</p></div>
                <div class="block-description">
                    <p>{{ block.blockDescription }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% case "backgroundImageDivider" %}
    <div class="divider" style="background-image: url({{ siteUrl }}/images/background-images{{ block.backgroundImage.one().getUrl() }});">
        <div class="standard-wrapper">
        <h2 class="divider-title">{{ block.dividerTitle }}</h2>
        <div class="divider-description">{{ block.dividerDescription }}</div>
        <div class="button-block">{{ block.button }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% case "blockTiles" %}
    <div class="block-inner">
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('sessionTiles').all() %}
    <div class="sessions-block">
            <img src="{{ siteUrl }}/images/session-images{{ entry.sessionTileImage.one().getUrl() }}" />
            <div class="inner-text">
                <h5 class="sessions-title">{{ entry.sessionTileTitle }}</h5>
                <div class="sessions-description">{{ entry.sessionTileDescription }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% default %}

{% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [relatedTo](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) parameter

```TWIG
{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(block).section('sessionTiles').all() %}
```

or even more simple the [short syntax](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#getting-target-elements-via-the-source-element)

```TWIG
{% for sessionTile in block.blockTilesContent.all() %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Robin! The relatedTo parameter has it showing the selected entries.